# Unable to pass JSON/JSON string in function parameter

Tags: javascript, json

I have stored json string in my db field like following which is a valid json:

```
{"contact_person_name":"abcd","address_line1":"line1","address_line2":"line2","postal_code":"1111","country_id":"2","state":"someState","city":"someCity"}
```

when I am trying to pass this json string variable ***requestData.fields_values*** in a function parameter it is being printed in console like following while clicking the anchor tag:

**literal not terminated before end of script**

my JavaScript function is following:

```
function performChangeRequest(vendorId, requestedData){
            console.log('data: ' + requestedData);
}
```

I am appending dynamically data like following:

```
<a href="javascript:performChangeRequest('${requestData.vendor_id}', '${requestData.fields_values}' )"></a>
```

If I print the first variable ***vendorId*** it is working fine.

Any help? I have tried looking around

Comment: When you save the object in the database, even though it is JSON, it is being retrieved as string

Comment: @hngr18 JSON *is* a string

Comment: The string contains these: "
So the tag gets broken (the href attribute is delimited by these)
 <a href="javascript:performChangeRequest('${requestData.vendor_id}', '${requestData.fields_values}' )"></a>
Do a string replace to change the JSON's " to \" (escaping the ")

Comment: Apologies, first time writing comments, wanted to do a carriage return and posted prematurely!

Comment: can you please write that for me as a parameter? I am getting a bit confused @hngr18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve the JSON from the database and set requestData.**fields_values**, instead of assigning

```
requestData.field_values = **data**
```

instead do

```
requestData.field_values = **data**.replace('"', '\\"')
```

If you don't have the ability to intercept this value as it is being retrieved from the database, try instead to change the anchor tag to something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:performChangeRequest('${requestData.vendor_id}', '${requestData.fields_values.replace('"', '\\"')}' )"></a>
```

In the function **performChangeRequest** do console.log('data: ' + JSON.parse(requestedData));